# Prove that if $o(a)=n$ then $o(a^{-1})=n$

Tags: group-theory

Let a $G$ be a finite group.
I need to prove that if the order of an element, $o(a)=n$, then $o(a^{-1})=n$.
My try:
$$(a^{-1})^n=(a^n)^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$$
But how now can I prove that there isn't a $1\le k <n$ so that $a^k=e$?

Comment: What is $o(a)$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The order of the element $a$